# Why RewriteRule doesn't apply?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, I know this is very frequently asked question, and I've looked in related question but no luck, so I'm gonna ask it.

I'm writing a file exchange service and I keep uploaded files stored on the server with names encoded by md5() function (there were some encoding issues, so I decided to store them like that), and I have their real names in database. Obviously I want user to be able to download files with their original names. I give files without any php, just giving the link with the path to file. I know that browser assign name to the downloaded file by taking the last part of its URL (i.e. what lies after last "/"). My plan is to give links like that

```
uploads/0/150/326ac5f4bb70bae757d2b72d77cd5d43.jpg/original_Name.jpg
```

so that browser would take what is after last "/" ("original_Name.jpg") and give this name to the downloading file. But I want it to be **actually** downloading the real existing file:

```
uploads/0/150/326ac5f4bb70bae757d2b72d77cd5d43.jpg
```

I thought I can accomplish that by adding a simple RewriteRule in my .htaccess, so I wrote:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule uploads/(.+)/.*$ uploads/$1
```

But it doesn't working. I keep getting this FILE NOT FOUND error:
*The requested URL /uploads/0/151/f7e18efaed5fc1cd13e59e77824f2806.jpg/1372903471104.jpg was not found on this server.*

Apparently it doesn't get rewrited at all. Any suggestions?

P.S. I got AllowOverride All in httpd.conf apache configuration file.
P.P.S. This is whole contents of my .htaccess file in case something in there can somehow affect my situation:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule uploads/(.+)/.*$ uploads/$1

php_value memory_limit 512M
```

ther other RewriteRule along with its RewriteCond aren't written by me it goes with Slim framework which I use in this project.

Comment: have you checked if your Apache rewrite_module is on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule uploads/([^.]+\.[^/]+)/[^/]+$ uploads/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Nope, it isn't helping.

Comment: First rule rewrites `/uploads/0/150/326ac5f4bb70bae757d2b72d77cd5d43.jpg/original_Name.jpg` to `/uploads/0/150/326ac5f4bb70bae757d2b72d77cd5d43.jpg` **internally** What happens when you open `http://test.com/uploads/0/150/326ac5f4bb70bae757d2b72d77cd5d43.jpg` directly?

Comment: I don't know if it's related with our matter but when I click "download" button the adress bar of my browser shows: http://d-loadme/uploads/0/155/2a95755c890eeef895928de3f724e731.jpg/1322858364364.jpg?download_url=%2Ff%2F155

Comment: What is `d-loadme` at the start?

Comment: domain name apparently

Comment: answering your qestion in the 2nd comment : the file downloading dialog window pops up, as expected.

Comment: Did't understand what you mean by `answering your qestion in the 2nd comment`

Comment: you asked "What happens when you open http://test.com/uploads/0/150/326ac5f4bb70bae757d2b72d77cd5d43.jpg directly?"

Comment: I also asked the location/path of your .htaccess?